# Building and deploying kettle with maven

Tags: maven, plugins, pentaho, kettle

i am using spring boot 2.0.3 as a restful api to call kettle. I have kettle in my maven build with core and engine, but It fails running my transform with plugin not found For Add XML Column, and I’m sure others. I can’t find a maven repo with the plugins Built for maven dependency.

i am using 8.1 but can revert to 7 easily.

i need to deploy it all as a maven build for security and process reasons.

cheers
a

Answer (score 0):

Checkout from github proper version of kettle, build it and install to local repository. 
I don't remember exactly, i built kettle long time ago, but i think kettle consists of several modules. 
engine-core
db-dialog
ui
plugin

You are missing on of them.